# where to put the textbox that for different UserControls to use?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

In my WPF program. I have a DataModel.cs, MainWindow.xaml & MainWindow.xaml.cs and many UserControl.xaml & UserControl.xaml.cs which are integrated into MainWindow.xaml in this way:

```
    <Border...>
        <UserControl1/>
    </Border>
    <Border...>
        <UserControl2/>
    </Border>
    ...
```

I am not sure if it can be called MVVM?

Some of my UserControl.xaml.cs need to use the same string for connection which should be typed on the UI textbox somewhere like this:

```
DataModel.connection.Connect("[textbox.text]");
```

My question is where do I put this textbox so that each UserControl can get access to it and how? Thanks.

Comment: 1. I think you need read more on MVVM, short answer, as long as you are not referencing and UI elements directly in you ViewModel, you can consider it MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a `string` property in your `DataModel` class:

```
public class DataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _text;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

...and bind the `TextBox` in the view to this `string` property:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Provided that you set the `DataContext` of the window to an instance of your `DataModel` class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new DataModel();
    }
}
```

...the source property (`Text`) will be updated whenever you type something into the `TextBox`. If you let the `UserControls` inherit the `DataContext` from the parent window, i.e. don't set the `DataContext` of the `UserControls` explicitly somewhere, they can bind to the very same `Text` property and get the latest value "automatically" as the `DataModel` implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event.

This is roughly how basic MVVM works.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you need read more on MVVM, short answer, as long as you are not referencing and UI elements directly in you ViewModel, you can consider it MVVM.
2. There are multiple ways you can do it, I would define and interface with

   public interface IProvideTextProperty {string SomeText{get;set;}}

   Implement this interface  in all UserControls that use this property
3. ON the UI have a textbox in MainWindow, Bind the textproperty of this TextBox to SomeText(viewmodel of MainWindow also implements IProvideTextProperty), in the setter, loop though all the viewmodels that are IProvideTextProperty and set the SomeProperty.

Comment: Hello I am not sure what to write in "get{ }" when implementing the interface in UserControl?